# Minimum rounds for rebalancing laundry

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for linear time algorithm for the below Laundry assignment.

There are N machines in a laundry. They have infinite capacity. Now a truck of cloths is unloaded for washing and randomly assigned to each machine. In this process manager missed to balance the load of cloths to clean. Now rebalancing is required.

Rebalancing proceeds in rounds. Every time a machine can transfer at most one cloth to each of its neighbors. Neighbors of the machine i are the machine i-1 and i+1 (machines 1 and N have only one neighbor each, 2 and N-1 respectively). The goal of rebalancing is to achieve that all machines have the same number of cloths.

Given the number of cloths initially assigned to each machine, you are asked to determine the minimal number of rounds needed to achieve the state when every machine has the same number of cloths, or to determine that such rebalancing is not possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). what is your actual question here?

Comment: try it with a few sample-inputs and paper and pencil. It's not that hard to come up with a solution to this problem that way.

Answer (score 0):

Let C be the total number of cloths. There is a solution if and only if N evenly divides C.

In such a solution, each machine has exactly C/N cloths. Let c_i be the number of cloths initially held by machine i. Define the *surplus* of machine i to be s_i = c_i - C/N. Note that surpluses may be negative; this is usually called a *deficit* in English.

Define f_{i,i+1} = sum_{j≤i} s_i and consider the exchanges made by machines i and i+1. The number of cloths sent from i to i+1 minus the number of cloths sent from i+1 to i must equal f_{i,i+1}, which can be seen by considering the number of cloths in 1..i over time.

Claim: the number of turns taken by the optimal solution is T = max_i |f_{i,i+1}|. Clearly this running time is necessary, since |f_{i,i+1}| decreases at most one per turn. The proof of sufficiency is by induction on T. The base case is when the T = 0. Then all f are zero too, and we're already done. Otherwise, every machine i such that f_{i,i+1} = T should send a cloth to i+1, and every machine i+1 such that f_{i,i+1} = -T should send a cloth to i. These machines have at least one cloth, since the flows indicate that they are giving out more than they take in, and the new configuration has decreased T by one.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getMinimumRounds(int[] machines) {
  int total = 0;
  int N = machines.length;
  for (int clothes: machines) {
      total += clothes;
  }

  if (total % N != 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not Possible");
  }

  int target = total / N;

  int rounds = 0;
  int diff =0;
  for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
      diff = machines[i]-target;
      machines[i+1] += diff;

      rounds = Math.max(rounds, Math.abs(diff));
  }

  return rounds;
}
```